# python django partial match regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

So i want to filter a queryset and get all objects that have a partial match to a word

```
queryset.filter(name=r'regex')
```

search term = app

- apple = true
- application = true
- aptitude = false
- stuff = false
- pineapple = true

I am really bad with regex any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need a regex for a partial match, use `contains`:

```
queryset.filter(name__contains='partial')
```

Or when you need a case-insensitive match:

```
queryset.filter(name__icontains='partial')
```

Comment: @mingle Be sure to read up on [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)!

Comment: Or if you are looking for something case insensitive you can use `icontains`.

Comment: As a plus add "name_icontains" so that its case insensitive.

Comment: Please note that it's a double underscore, so thats name__contains (or name__icontains) and not name_contains